# Understanding PHY_LE_1M vs PHY_LE_1M_MASK in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy device(smartwatch) that works on BLE v4.1 and am developing an Android application for the same.

I have basic understanding related to BLE PHY but couldn't find anything related to PHY LE 1M and PHY LE 1M MASK. There is a brief here in Android app about [PHY_LE_1M](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#PHY_LE_1M) and [PHY_LE_1M_MASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#PHY_LE_1M_MASK) but couldn't understand it well.

Can you please share some details related to the same? I want to use it in connect method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback,%20int)).

Also what is the default selection in Android if not specified and do I have to specify the same? Main concern is because the device in BLE v4.1 and commonly used BLE in phones are v4.2 and v5.0 as I have found for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is probably to pass 0 as the `phy` parameter (the same as passing `PHY_OPTION_NO_PREFERRED`, which evaluates to 0 as well).

If you want to specify an explicit transmission mode, use `PHY_LE_1M_MASK` as it is the only one supported by BLE 4. The other ones have been introduced with BLE 5.

The constants ending in `_MASK` seem to be for use in `connectGatt` while the constants without `_MASK` are for use in `onPhyUpdate`.

I don't know what the default transmission mode / PHY is. It might be LE 1M, or it might be determined once more information about the BLE device is available.

Comment: When specifying the `phy` parameter in `connectGatt`, you shall use `_MASK` options, per the documentation, i.e. not the non-`_MASK` options.

Comment: @Emil: You are assuming that whoever wrote the documentation fully understood the purpose of the mask constants. As I wrote above, they don't make much sense in the first place. So I wouldn't be surprised if the confusion continued in the documentation. Anyway, the constants with and without `_MASK` evaluate to the same number and they cannot be changed by Google without breaking old software. So it doesn't really matter.

Comment: No? `PHY_LE_CODED` is 3 while `PHY_LE_CODED_MASK` is 4. I'm not seeing why this would not make sense. If you want to establish a connection using 2M or Coded PHY, you set `phy` to `PHY_LE_CODED_MASK | PHY_2M_MASK`. The non-mask versions are used in for example https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onPhyUpdate(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int,%20int). Although I admit it would have been better designed to just have one set of values. I think they just copied the design from HCI.

Comment: @Emil: You are correct. I wasn't aware of `onPhyUpdate`. They have created a very tricky interface. I've updated my answer accordingly.