# Android BLE connection on specific phy

Tags: android, bluetooth, kernel, bluetooth-lowenergy

In this case, we are using "`BluetoothDevice.connectGatt(ctx, auto, callback, transport, phy, handler)`" to connect from an Android device to a BLE peripheral. Refer to [line 686](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/blob/004e6645dfb391c253c13a8b75d38a86b0aeacc2/ble/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/android/ble/BleManagerHandler.java#L686) [on this NordicSemiconductor Android-BLE-Library source file named BleManagerHandler.java](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/blob/main/ble/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/android/ble/BleManagerHandler.java).

We are passing ["phy = PHY_LE_1M_MASK"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#PHY_LE_1M_MASK) in. However, the HCI snoop log shows the command on HCI goes with also both the 2M_PHY and CODED_PHY enabled. The snippet of log looks like:

```
Command Opcode: LE Extended Create Connection (0x2043)
......
Initiating PHYs: 0x7, LE Coded, LE 2M, LE 1M
   0000 0... = Reserved: 0x00
   .... .1.. = LE Coded: True
   .... ..1. = LE 2M: True
   .... ...1 = LE 1M: True
```

Question 1: Is this expected and right logic? Since we are passing only 1M, I would expect it to set only 1M on HCI.

Question 2: No matter whether this is correct or not, how can we disable those 2 bits for 2M and coded phy on HCI? Do we have to modify privileged libraries or kernel? Or can it be in a normal app or library?

Reference: [A previous SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337903/understanding-phy-le-1m-vs-phy-le-1m-mask-in-android) helped me to trace to the source code locations of the above.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe another app wants to connect using all PHYs?

Comment: Not sure. Another app may want to use all phy thus the library has to change one-phy to all phy? If that is the case, where to change that library? Or I'm seeing the HCI call made by another app? Not likely because I'm seeing exactly the same number of calls made by our code. Thanks anyway.